# Property reader in spring

Tags: spring, properties

I'm using `org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` for reading properties and loading them.

I want print all the properties loaded by them,please help?

Comment: "print"...? Where from?

Comment: What you have tried? code please

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to print out the properties that the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` has loaded and will use, then you may do best to subclass `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` and log out the properties yourself. Its easy enough - for example:

```
public class LoggingPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer extends PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(LoggingPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.class);

    @Override
    protected Properties mergeProperties() throws IOException {
        Properties props = super.mergeProperties();
        for (String name : props.stringPropertyNames()) {
            LOG.debug(name + ": " + props.getProperty(name));
        }
        return props;
    }
}
```

And then update your Spring config:

```
<bean class="LoggingPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:myprops.properties"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: i want to print properties on jsp file like if i do a get call,i should be able to print all the properties it has loaded to the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using log4j, you can log it by adding:

```
<logger name="org.springframework.beans.factory.config">
        <level value="info" />
</logger>
```

It will show:

```
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer - Loading properties file from class path resource [myApp.properties]
```